# Get the login of a user in the JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

I work on an J2EE application with Struts and I want to get the login of a user in a JSP page.
The method connect in my `UserDAO` is:

```
 public String Connect(String login,String password) {
    
    List<Long> results= null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
    queryString.append("Select id from Utilisateur user ")
      .append("where user.login= :logi and user.password= :passwor ");
    try {
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString.toString());
        query.setString("logi",login);
        query.setString("passwor",CryptUtil.md5(password));
        results =query.list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
     if(results.size() != 0) {
         long id=(Long) results.get(0);
         user = (Utilisateur) session.get(Utilisateur.class, id);
         session.getTransaction().commit();
        if (user != null){
             statut= user.getStatut();
             id_us= user.getIdutilisateur();
         }else{
             statut= null;
             id_us= null;
         }
     }
     return statut;
}
```

Now I want to get this login in a JSP page `index.jsp`.

**My class `USER.java` is:**

```
 public class Utilisateur {

private Long idutilisateur;

private String login;
private String password;
private String statut;
 
public Long getIdutilisateur() {
    return idutilisateur;
}
public void setIdutilisateur(Long idutilisateur) {
    this.idutilisateur = idutilisateur;
} 
public String getStatut() {
    return statut;
}
public void setStatut(String statut) {
    this.statut = statut;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

I use a service method ans also an action method.

```
 public String Connect(Utilisateur admin) {
     String statut= null;
     Long id = null;
    if (admin != null){
        utilisateurDAO.Connect(admin.getLogin(), admin.getPassword());
        statut= utilisateurDAO.getStatut();
        id= utilisateurDAO.getId_us();
        if(statut != null && !statut.isEmpty()){
            statut= statut.toUpperCase();
            session.put("id", id);
            session.put("login", admin.getLogin());
            session.put("statut", utilisateurDAO.getStatut());
            return statut;
        }else{
            return "input";
        }
    }else{
        return "input";
    }
    
}
```

**UserAction:**

```
 public String Connect() {
    uService = new UtilisateurService();
    statut = uService.Connect(admin);
    return statut;
}
```

this action method return the statut that I want to get in the JSP page, how can I do it ?

Now I can get ths statut un the JSP page, but how can I use it in a `<c:choose>` this is what I did:

```
 <s:property value="#session.principal.statut"/>
 <c:set var="type" value="#session.principal.statut"/>

   
 <c:choose>
 <c:when test="${type eq 'ADMIN'}">
 <%@ include file="../menu/menu.jsp"%>
    
 </c:when>
 <c:when test="${type1 eq 'USER'}">
 <%@ include file="../menu/menuother.jsp"%>
 </c:when>
 </c:choose>
```

Comment: i want to get the return value of the method Connect in a JSP page !!

Comment: Where did you declare `statut`? Is it a class member?

Comment: yes it is. i will update  my question with the my class.

Comment: You can reference `statut` using EL/OGNL in your JSP page using its getter method.

Comment: i don't know how to do it. i have update my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea using accessing DAO objects in jsp pages, is like mixing data access layer with the presentation layer. You can find some explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044125/jsp-connecting-to-a-database) for instance.

Instead, I recommend to execute the login method in a servlet. So, I guess you have a html form with login and password fields. Then in the POST method you can specify the url that will end up executing your servlet, which will contain a call to your method **connect**.

Answer (score 0):

After authentication you would probably put the user to the http session map, so you don't need to do authentication twice or more time you want to get into jsp page, which can only display the user if it's logged in.

```
 if(results.size() != 0) {
     long id=(Long) results.get(0);
     user = (Utilisateur) session.get(Utilisateur.class, id);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
    if (user != null){
      ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("principal", user);
```

now in the JSP you can get this user

```
<s:property value="#session.principal.statut"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, now how can i use this statut in a <c:choose>??

Comment: <s:property value="#session.principal.statut"/>
 <c:set var="type1" value="#session.principal.statut"/>
  
       
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${type1 eq 'ADMIN'}">
     <%@ include file="../menu/menu.jsp"%>
        
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${type1 eq 'SECR'}">
      <%@ include file="../menu/MenuSecretaire.jsp"%>
    </c:when>

Comment: <c:set var="type1"><s:property value="#session.principal.statut"/></c:set>